# Response.Redirect does not change the URL for Page1.aspx to Page2.aspx

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect

I'm using `Response.Redirect` to redirect the user from **ProductListPage.aspx** to **DocumentListPage.aspx** and to pass an id using the query string.

```
protected void Click_btnHiddenRow(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Response.Redirect("DocumentListPage.aspx?id=" +
     this.txtSelectedID.Value);
}
```

The page content is changing so the user is actually redirected to the second page, the id is passed too, however the URL in the browser is still `http://localhost:60559/Pages/ProductListPage.aspx`.

I'm experiencing some other not relevant anomalies and I thought that this might be the problem.

Is the situation with the URL normal, when using **Response.Redirect**?

~~~

I would like also to add one of the anomalies that might actually be relevant to the situation.

In the **DocumentListPage.aspx** page I've got a button with code-behind event handler. However when this button is clicked, it is not going into the event method, instead the break point in the **ProductListPage.aspx**'s Page_Load event method fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the situation with the URL normal, when using Response.Redirect?

Yes, if you used an AJAX request to invoke this `Click_btnHiddenRow` function. It's unclear what control this event handler is bound to but if you are using AJAX to call it, that would explain the behavior.

Comment: Actually btnHiddenRow is a hidden button. I've got a table and when the user clicks on one of the rows btnHiddenRow is clicked via JQuery. Do you suggest that this might be the problem? If yes - any thoughts for a workaround?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem. The workaround is to perform the redirect in the success callback of your jQuery AJAX call and not on the server. Here's how to redirect using javascript: `window.location.href = '/DocumentListPage.aspx?id=123';`. But if you are going to redirect it is absolutely meaningless to use AJAX. The whole point of AJAX is to stay on the same page and refresh only some portion of it. So as a workaround I would recommend you removing the AJAX call and performing a full postback to the server and you will be able to redirect as you currently do.

Comment: Fixed! : ) Thank you very much @Darin Dimitrov

Answer (score 0):

This situation would be normal for `Server.Transfer` but its not normal for `Response.Redirect`. Redirect sends following response to the browser:

```
HTTP 1.0 302 Object Moved 
Location: http://example.com
```

causing it to fire GET request for new resource. Judging from event handler `Click_btnHiddenRow` (hidden part) Darin is probably right - you are doing an ajax request?